# Removed 2 rows containing missing values (`geom_segment()`) while there are no missing values in data

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-segment

I am plotting results from Redundancy analysis using ggplot and I got a warning:

```
Removed 2 rows containing missing values (`geom_segment()`).
```

This warning lead to the missing two arrows in the figure (for variable "Family labor" and "Hired labor").

[output figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS2e6.png)

However, the data used for plot the segment do not include missing values.

Please see the below code for plot and the data for geom_segment.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = sp2,aes(RDA1,RDA2),fill="dodgerblue1",shape=22,size=4.5)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set2')+
  geom_text_repel(data = sp,aes(RDA1,RDA2,label=sp2$Group),color="black",size=6)+
  geom_segment(data = yz,aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = RDA1, yend = RDA2,shape=grp.yz$Group,fill=grp.yz$Group), 
               arrow = arrow(angle=22.5,length = unit(0.35,"cm"),
                             type = "closed"),linetype=1, size=0.7,colour = "gray70")+
  geom_point(data = yz,aes(RDA1,RDA2,fill=grp.yz$Group),size=4.5,shape=21)+
  #scale_shape_manual(values = c(22:23))+
  geom_text_repel(data = yz2,aes(RDA1,RDA2,label=yz2$label),size=6)+
 # scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set2')+
  labs(x=paste("RDA 1 (", format(100 *ii$cont[[1]][2,1], digits=3), "%)", sep=""),
       y=paste("RDA 2 (", format(100 *ii$cont[[1]][2,2], digits=3), "%)", sep=""))+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0,linetype=3,size=1,color="gray50") + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=0,linetype=3,size=1,color="gray50")+
  guides(shape=guide_legend(title=NULL,color="black"),
         fill=guide_legend(title=NULL))+
  theme_bw()+theme(panel.grid=element_blank())+
  #theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size = 13)) +
  #theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="white", size=0.2, linetype="solid", colour ="black")) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(colour="black",size=14),
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black",size=14)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(colour="black",size=14),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black",size=14))
```

Data for geom_segment:

```
RDA1        RDA2 id
COVID_experience_yes     0.079791785  0.14111628  1
COVID_lockdown           0.144604188 -0.27902139  2
Family_labour           -0.042481422 -0.21235206  3
Hired_labour             0.317842345  0.18081804  4
Information_access       0.217181899 -0.16861407  5
Group_membership        -0.021734340 -0.07815768  6
Shortest_distance        0.100966592 -0.22021657  7
Precipitation           -0.115402219  0.22859724  8
Temperature             -0.005440390 -0.16467817  9
Elevation                0.005769102 -0.01466336 10
Slope                   -0.054949492 -0.02525952 11
Production_area_ha       0.903160453  0.12789322 12
Borrow_money             0.405894836  0.02389362 13
BMP_adoption             0.336062487  0.04447044 14
Fish_selling_price       0.015581173  0.03274025 15
Distance_nearest_market  0.404554579 -0.75961346 16
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help.